# Could not install owa-epanet in python

Tags: python, cmake

I am new to python.
I need to install owa-epanet on my computer, so I used the code `pip install owa-epanet`.
But it returned the error shown below:

```
C:\Users\Ziyuan>pip install owa-epanet
Collecting owa-epanet
  Using cached owa-epanet-2.2.3.tar.gz (800 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: owa-epanet
  Building wheel for owa-epanet (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\ziyuan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ziyuan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q6ub27xj\\owa-epanet_dc5c9205daa9406797dfe7c2d9957cd2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ziyuan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q6ub27xj\\owa-epanet_dc5c9205daa9406797dfe7c2d9957cd2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Ziyuan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-g59ckj0l'
       cwd: C:\Users\Ziyuan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q6ub27xj\owa-epanet_dc5c9205daa9406797dfe7c2d9957cd2\
  Complete output (153 lines):


  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/Ziyuan/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-q6ub27xj/owa-epanet_dc5c9205daa9406797dfe7c2d9957cd2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

    could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/Ziyuan/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-q6ub27xj/owa-epanet_dc5c9205daa9406797dfe7c2d9957cd2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
    The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
    that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
    unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
    Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/Ziyuan/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-q6ub27xj/owa-epanet_dc5c9205daa9406797dfe7c2d9957cd2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/Ziyuan/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-q6ub27xj/owa-epanet_dc5c9205daa9406797dfe7c2d9957cd2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles JOM (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
    The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    To use the JOM generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
    that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
    unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
    Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/Ziyuan/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-q6ub27xj/owa-epanet_dc5c9205daa9406797dfe7c2d9957cd2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/Ziyuan/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-q6ub27xj/owa-epanet_dc5c9205daa9406797dfe7c2d9957cd2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles JOM (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ********************************************************************************
  scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

  Building windows wheels for Python 3.7 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.
  Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  ********************************************************************************
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for owa-epanet
```

Could you please give me ideas about what should I do next?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please give me ideas about what should I do next?

Since CMake explicitly says that it can't find the command-line version of the Windows [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) compiler (`cl.exe`) in your path in order to build an usable version of `owa-epanet`, the simplest courses of action would probably be to:

- Ensure that Visual Studio (or its toolset at least) is installed properly.
- Ensure that `cl.exe` is available and correctly detected from the command line.

---

*Note that if you want to ensure maximum compatibility, you can get older versions of Visual Studio [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/).*